# Invoke R from Java on windows and Linux

Tags: java, r

I am writing a Java application. I want to invoke R with that application. Now, I have found Rserve, but the proble is as follows: the program, once finished, should work on Linux as well as Windows AND the user does not necessarily have R on his computer, so everything necessary should end up in the Jar.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least a couple of choices:

1. Bundle the standard R distribution with your program.
2. Bundle [renjin](http://www.renjin.org/) with your program. This is an implementation of R using the JVM.

Both options are likely to bloat your package size by quite a bit, introduce installation and maintenance hassles, etc. It's probably better to just specify that R has to be installed to use your code.

Comment: how is this "bundling" actually done? Everyone seems to know this but no one ever writes a "how to".

Comment: I did try renjin, but the installation simply does not work, as the installation of frameworks NEVER works with me. is there ANY possible way to bundle R with my program? I am really desperae , sitting on this for almost 4 hours with no other help than: it simply does not work!